# Python urrlib2 using HTTPS proxy to request HTTPS ressource

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, urllib2

when using Python 2.7s urllib2 I do not seem to be able to retrieve a resource from a HTTPS server while using a SSL secured proxy server, i.e. to following:

```
CLIENT ---- (HTTPS) ---> PROXY ---- (https) --- > SERVER
```

Of cause to get through the proxy server one uses CONNECT. Any ideas?

Alternative question: when using CONNECT one needs to setup a completly independent 2. SSL session inside the tunnel, right? How could one do that in python as simply calling ssl.wrap_socket does not do the trick...?

Comment: You should consider switch to module 'requests'. Much easier to use. Here is a relevant section of proxy http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: @AnthonyKong fun fact - it does not work in requests either. It simply sends raw traffic without encryption to the proxy, who rightfully terminates the connection

Comment: Which OS and version of python are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyKong I am using 2.7 on Mac OS X